# Do Tom Hanks and Halle Berry meet on earth in Cloud Atlas?

Tags: cloud-atlas

Zachry (Tom Hanks) and Meronym (Halle Berry) meet in some possibly post-apocalyptic forest. And Meronym uses some kind of satellite dish to contact someone in space. Later they are shown not on earth, Zachry points out earth in the night sky.

[image: Zachry and Meronym]

Were they on earth when they met?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That story [takes place](http://cloudatlas.wikia.com/wiki/Sloosha%27s_Crossin%27_an%27_Ev%27rythin%27_After)

> in the distant future, in a world following a nuclear holocaust.
>
> The cities destroyed, humans now live in small tribes, including *Zachry's* Valleymen tribe **on the island of Ha-why (Hawaii)**.

The last scene is [an epilogue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Atlas_%28film%29#Plot):

> **Zachry is revealed to have been telling these stories to his numerous grandchildren on one of Earth's colonies**, a planet with two moons, revealing that they had succeeded in sending a message to the colonies and were rescued.